# Import struct from main package into another package in golang

Tags: go, import, package, parent

I have two packages `main` and `test`. I'm working on `test` package and I need to import a struct that is decalared inside `main` package, but it seems to be impossible!
This is my directory structure:

```
root/
├── test/
│   └── test.go
├── main.go
└── go.mod
```

`go.mod`:

```golang
module my_project

go 1.20
```

`main.go`:

```golang
package main

import "my_project/test"

type MainStruct struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    test.TestFunction()
}
```

`test.go`:

```golang
package test

func TestFunction() {
    // I want to access 'MainStruct' here
}
```

**Is it possible to import from parent package?**

Comment: There is no parent/child package hierarchy, and you cannot import `main` (even if this were possible, you would have an import cycle which is also not allowed)

Comment: Declare the type in a third package. Import that package in `my_project` and `my_project/test`.